# How to use django cache with REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, caching

I'm fairly new to Django and try to get a working backend. So far, my backend is working fine, but I don't know, how to respond with custom data:

**What I have:**

- Angular Frontend
- Django (REST) backend
- A working cache

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to call an endpoint (lets say backend/weather). When I call this endpoint, I want to check my cache for a weather value. If there is one, I want to send it to the client. If there is none, I want to make an API call, store the retrieved value in my cache and send the value to the client. How can I do this. This is what I have so far:

*views.py*

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Weather
from .serializers import WeatherSerializer

from django.core.cache import cache
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json


class WeatherView(APIView):

    def get(self):
        if(cache.get('temp') == None):
            url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + '...';
            serialized_data = urlopen(url).read()
            data = json.loads(serialized_data)
            print(data)

            cache.set('weatherdata', data, 3600)
        else:
            data = cache.get('weatherdata')

        serializer_class = WeatherSerializer(data)

        responseJSON = JSONRenderer().render(serializer_class.data)

        return Response(responseJSON)
```

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Weather


class WeatherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    temp = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    iconName = serializers.CharField()
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('weather', views.WeatherView)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I get the data from the API. My cache setting and getting are also working. But I don't know how to respond with custom data. I'm getting the following error when calling backend/weather:

```
TypeError at /weather
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/weather
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're just storing the weather data in cache, why do you create a model for it and use a ModelSerializer? Use a Serializer, as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), to which you pass the data you receive from the 3rd party api. Also you're only fetching weather information, you shouldn't create a full ViewSet (which performs all the CRUD operations), just use a simple `APIView` that renders the `Serializer.data` to a `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When doing so, I get the following error: AttributeError: type object 'WeatherView' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Comment: Your view is an APIView so you can't use `router` to define the url. Just define the url manually as you would for any view. `get_extra_actions()` is a method of a `ViewSet`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you, that solved the problem! Unfortunately I get another error. I will edit my question.

Comment: your url path should point to a view function not a view class: `WeatherView.as_view()`

Comment: That solved the error! But now I get: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Also one other thing: If the only thing you're going to do is pass the data back as json in your API, you don't need a serializer at all, since your data is already serialised. Serializers are for serialising python objects (e.g. a Weather object, doesn't need to be a model, like the Comment in the Serializer documentation I linked in my first comment).

Comment: `def get(self, request):`

Comment: Thank you so much, with the 2 last comments it's working like a charm!